# The (&(objectClass=user)(|(displayName)) search filter is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

Error:Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: The (&(objectClass=user)(|(displayName)) search filter is invalid.

```
emailAddress = "";
displayName = "Smith";

DirectorySearcher oSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
//oSearch.Filter = "name=" + displayName;
//oSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(sAMAccountName = displayName))";
oSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(displayName))";
SearchResult oResult = oSearch.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry oEntry = oResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

emailAddress = oEntry.Properties["emailAddress"].Value.ToString();
```

Trying to get email address based on display name.

Tried these as well.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(&(displayName = {Smith})) 


oSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(&(displayName = {Smith})))", displayName);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search filter is invalid/incorrect since you're incorrectly using the OR(|) operator.

Though there is no condition given in the question, I'll assume a case that you're trying to find the email-address of the user whose display name is "Smith".

In this case, your filter would be:

```
oSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayName=Smith))";
  // check the placement of brackets and the operator carefully as shown above.
  // if you need to search for names starting with "Smith", use wildcard: (displayName=Smith*)
SearchResult oResult = oSearch.FindOne();

if (null != oResult) // check for null values everywhere in your code to avoid NPE
DirectoryEntry oEntry = oResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

if (null != oEntry) // check for null values, else NP exception will be thrown
emailAddress = oEntry.Properties["emailAddress"].Value.ToString();
```

Please refer the TechNet article [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi, yes. I'm trying to find email of user with display name of Smith. But now it gives me an error of :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @JAYY - This is a null-pointer exception. Please share the exact exception being encountered and add it in your question. Please do let me know once you do that.

Comment: I see. Okay. If i have an input called displayName which changes, then it will be solely (displayName) right?

Comment: @JAYY - No, in case if your displayName is variable, please use the wildcard: `(&(objectClass=user)(displayName=*))`